# android syntax error database helper class

Tags: android

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE users_data (S.NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  DATE NUMERIC, REASON TEXT, AMOUNT NUMERIC)

Comment: You can't have dots in column names

Comment: Enclose `S.NO` inside square brackets or backticks: `[S.NO]`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `.` in column names, if you want them to have so badly, you'll have to wrap them with `[` and `]`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_data (
    S.NO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    DATE NUMERIC, 
    REASON TEXT, 
    AMOUNT NUMERIC
)
```

The above snippet is incorrect while the below is the correct one

```
CREATE TABLE users_data (
    [S.NO] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    DATE NUMERIC, 
    REASON TEXT, 
    AMOUNT NUMERIC
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the error log you received with the above change?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "+": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE users_data ( [S.NO] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  [DATE] DECIMAL, [REASON] TEXT, [AMOUNT] DECIMAL) + ";

Comment: DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:35)

Comment: DatabaseHelper.addData(DatabaseHelper.java:45)
                      at com.example.dell.ikka.Main2Activity.AddData(Main2Activity.java:72)
                      at com.example.dell.ikka.Main2Activity$2.onClick(Main2Activity.java:57)